# same ip and subnet in 2 different bridges

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, bridge, libvirt

I am trying to create 2 different virtual networks in the same ip range (not using NAT) in virt manager.

This doesn't work with the gui or editing the xml of the new virtual network.

Is creating bridges with brctl and configuring the addresses with dnsmasq the way to follow ?